# PHP Create Query from array, can't pick out both indexes in foreach statement

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a query from a form that passes ID and Details fields, the post array looks like this:

```
array(2) { 
["ID"]=> array(9) 
    { 
    [0]=> string(3) "10a" 
    [1]=> string(3) "10b" 
    [2]=> string(3) "10c" 
    [3]=> string(3) "10d" 
    [4]=> string(3) "10e" 
    [5]=> string(3) "10f"  
    } 
["Details"]=> array(9) 
    { 
    [0]=> string(19) "This is textfield 1" 
    [1]=> string(17) "This is textfield 2" 
    [2]=> string(0) "" 
    [3]=> string(0) "" 
    [4]=> string(0) "" 
    [5]=> string(0) ""
    } 
}
```

The ID is hardcoded into the page and always passed, the details can be filled out by the user as needed.

```
 if ($_POST['OthProb']['Details'] != '') {
        // Catch issue text and assign to variable
        foreach ( $_POST['OthProb']['Details'] as $key => $value) {
            $id = $_POST['OthProb']['ID']->$key;
            $dets = $value;
        // Focus on fields with values and join the array values together in a query string
        if ($dets != ''){
        $string = "INSERT into $table (AccountID, OtherID, ID, Details) VALUES ($_POST[AccountID], $_POST[OtherID], '".$id.", '".$dets."')";
            $sql = $DBH->prepare($string);
            // $sql->execute();
            // var_dump ($id);                
   }   
   }

}
```

creates the following

```
 "INSERT into tbl_problems (AccountID, OtherID, ID, Details) VALUES (80, 80, '10f, 'This is Title issue')"
```

The 'Details' are outputting correctly, but its cycling all the way through the ID's to the last one, is that because I'm nesting a foreach? What would be the best way to structure the loop?

Comment: Just as a side note, you may want to add an extra single quote in this line (right after the `.$id."`): `$string = "INSERT into $table (AccountID, OtherID, ID, Details) VALUES ($_POST[AccountID], $_POST[OtherID], '".$id.", '".$dets."')";` becomes `$string = "INSERT into $table (AccountID, OtherID, ID, Details) VALUES ($_POST[AccountID], $_POST[OtherID], '".$id."', '".$dets."')";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace this line:

```
$id = $_POST['OthProb']['ID']->$key;
```

by

```
$id = $_POST['OthProb']['ID'][$key];
```

Comment: Awesome, I swear I tried that yesterday, I must have made a mistake elsewhere! Works anyway, thanks very much.